# Any Operator which concatenates like x = y + x

Tags: c#, operators

We know that `+=` operator does this

```
x += y
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x + y
```

But is there an operator that does this

```
x = y + x
```

In integers `x + y = y + x`

its fine. But I want String concatenation.

Comment: `x+y=y+x` Then what's the point ?

Comment: commutativity is a nice thing...

Comment: @Dev: The `+` and `+=` operators are also used for concatenation (which is not commutative, as opposed to addition).

Comment: Think of string concatenation - big difference between x + y and y + x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an operator for what you are trying to do, but you can also use an extension method:

```
public static string AddBefore(this string value, string before)
{
    return before + value;
}
```

Then obviously call it like so:

```
x = x.AddBefore(y);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve the same result is

```
    x.Insert(0, y);
```

Comment: That's another way of looking.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you should go to all the massive effort of typing the longhand `x = y + x` because it is clear and easily maintainable code. If you overload operators with mysterious meanings then the code just becomes much more difficult to follow.

+= has a clear and well defined meaning, and the result relfects te order of the parameters (`x += y` keeps the strings in the order x, y). Having a statement like `x ?= y` that produces y,x would be a very confusing construct IMHO.

You could write an extension method like Prepend() to make the meaning clearer but that would be more typing than the original expression, so probably pointless.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. You can use `+=` and the result should be the same, since `x + y == y + x`.

For strings consider `Concat`, `Format` methods or `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
StringBuilder.Insert Method (Int32, Boolean)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xzfkkwa.aspx